# Riddled with (w)holes

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

With holes, I hold.

With holes, I am whole.

Try to make more, and there are less.

Try to make more, and I am less.

What am I?

Comment: I have asked someone this riddle before, and I have heard answers that compare well enough to my own.  If you have an answer that matches the riddle, even if it's not my original answer, I will accept it as long as your reasoning is thorough.

Comment: Suggested title: "*[Riddled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/riddled)* with (w)holes"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is

> a **Net**
>
>  Reasoning:
>
>  With holes, I hold.
>  -It holds things inside even though it is made of holes. Like fishing or butterfly net.
>
>  With holes, I am whole.
>  -A net is complete even with all the holes (empty space).
>
>  Try to make more, and there are less.
>  -If you cut a hole in a net, there are now less holes than what you started with (pretty cool actually)
>
>  Try to make more, and I am less.
>  -Once you cut a hole in a net, it now has less value/functionality than before.

Comment: This is 100% correct, with the exact reasoning to each line.  Well done!  I am glad that once the answer was found, none of the lines were ambiguous.

Comment: +1 for the 'pretty cool actually'!

Comment: Awesome, very clever question! took me a while to come up with that answer, glad to hear it's correct :)

Answer (score 4):

`What am I?`

> A **sponge**.

---

`With holes, I hold.`

> A sponge has **holes**, but it holds water by soaking it up.

`With holes, I am whole.`

> Although a sponge has holes, it is **undamaged** and in one piece.

`Try to make more, and there are less.`

> Try to make more **water**, and there are less because the sponge soaks it up.

`Try to make more, and I am less.`

> Try to make more **clean dishes** by scrubbing with your sponge and eventually it will <s>break</s> tear.  <sub>$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;$A better word to describe it, as opposed to "break". $\Large\;\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\Lsh}$</sub>

---

This is not the answer, as the answer has already been accepted, but I would like to share this thought.

Answer (score 3):

A possible alternative?

You are

> the universe.

---

*With holes, I hold*

> The universe has black holes, but it contains everything.

*With holes, I am whole*

> The universe is entire despite having black holes.

*Try to make more, and there are less*

> Black holes consume everything surrounding it, so less matter.

*Try to make more, and I am less*

> More black holes means more matter being swallowed up, so there is less in the universe.

Comment: This deserves my upvote, but dang this bloody voting limit... I am sure Stephen Hawking would like this one :)

Comment: My one gripe is that black holes don't remove matter from the universe. Otherwise, solid answer!